# hide the images going outside the div

Tags: html, css, overflow

bgpattern, illustratewoman class images should be hidden outside the div but the image is visible outside the card div also. For me, the images only should be displayed inside the div but not outside. Box class image should display on the inner and outer side of the div.

CSS even though I tried `overflow: hidden` for card class but it hides all the images going outside but for me, box image should not be hidden I tried to add for bgpatternimg, illustratewoman it doesn't work.

[image: image goes outside card image]

```css
card {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  height: 70vh;
  width: 130vh;
  border-radius: 3%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: 15vh;
}

.bgpatternimg {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: -70vh;
  top: -30vh;
  width: 120vh;
}

.illustratewoman {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10vh;
  left: -10vh;
  width: 60vh;
  height: 50vh;
}

.boximg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 22vh;
  bottom: 4vh;
  left: vh;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="bgpattern">
      <img class="bgpatternimg" src="images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg" alt="bgpattern">
    </div>
    <div class="illustratewoman">
      <img class="illuswoman" src="images/illustration-woman-online-desktop.svg" alt="illustratewoman">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img class="boximg" src="images/illustration-box-desktop.svg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please change it so it is a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

you're positioning `absolute` which means it'll make the position relative to the nearest static/relative positioned parent or grandparent. you're better off using another strategy without absolute positioning, then make your widths and heights `100%`

Answer (score 0):

### change style file

hello you should change the style to this code

```css
.card{
  position:absolute;
  background-color: white;
  height:70vh;
  width:130vh;
  border-radius: 3%;
  position:relative;
  margin:auto;
  top:15vh;
}
.bgpattern {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: -70vh;
    top: -30vh;
    width: 120vh;
}

.illustratewoman {
    width: 60vh;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10vh;
    left: -10vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 22vh;
    bottom: 4vh;
    left: 28vh;
}
```